# Add-On Index Page Throwing Parse Error That Is Not Correct

Tags: templates, control-panel, list, addons

EE 5.3.0

When I go to the `Add-Ons` section of my control panel I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /.../.../public_html/.../ee/EllisLab/Addons/rte/ext.rte.php on line 19
```

When I go to that line in the file (which I haven't touched and would never dream of messing with), I can see that the line in question has no issues. It's just a `$docs_url` with an expressionengine url as the value. There is no unexpected '.'

I have used a url path to get into two of my plugins directly, bypassing the `Add-Ons` list page, and they seemed to work fine. It's just the `Add-Ons` list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrm, well that line in `ext.rte.php` in the `5.3.0` release is:

```
var $docs_url       = DOC_URL.'add-ons/rte/control_panel/index.html';
```

So based on that error, I would assume the `DOC_URL` constant is not yet defined, or isn't being type interpereted as a string.

So try this:

```
var $docs_url = '';
```

If the pages loads, this smells like it could be a bug; start by using a search tool to determine *where* that `DOC_URL` constant is defined, and make sure it is getting a valid string value. You could also try hardcoding that variable to a valid value and if it works, it's another hint that `DOC_URL` isn't being defined.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my `ext.rte.php` file that variable actually is not using the `DOC_URL`. It is `var $docs_url  = 'https://docs.expressionengine.com/v4/add-ons/rte/control_panel/index.html';` In any case, I removed it as you suggested and the page is now loading. I checked to make sure nothing was happening to the rich text editor in other places that I'm using it, and there seems to be no problems. This is odd because I do NOT touch the EE core classes, so I don't know what could have changed to cause this.

Comment: I have faced this same error and checked to find this constant defined in any files.

I have found the two files where this constant is defined. 
1) system\ee\installer_5.3.0\controllers\wizard.php
2) system\ee\legacy\libraries\Core.php

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ray4i2

Comment: I had the same problem Installed Version: 5.3.2 Build: 22-4-2020 I did edit the file found in /ee/EllisLab/Addons/rte/ext.rte.php and changed line 19 into var $docs_url  = 'add-ons/rte/control_panel/index.html'; . The error was gone, have been working since then intensively with the site without problems. Reported this as well to Robin Sowell.